# What exactly is happening when a pipe is followed by a command grouping?

Tags: shell, command-line, pipe

I saw an expression like `command1 | {command2;command3;command4}` and I was thinking what this actually means, I know the pipe symbol, I know that `{...}` forces to run the commands inside the curly brackets in the main shell, but I am puzzled what they mean in combination.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't really matter how complex the parts of a pipeline are, you can often just visualize them as separate scripts if you want (especially in shells like `bash` which will run each part of a pipeline in a subshell anyway).

The script

```
command2
command3
command4
```

... which *roughly* is what `{ command2; command3; command4; }` translates into (not taking into account that `{ ...; }` nominally means that the commands are not run in a subshell),
is given input from the execution of

```
command1
```

Depending on what those three commands in the first script are doing, one or several of them will likely consume the input from `command1`, and if one or several of them are producing any output, that will go to the next part of the pipeline, or to the terminal or wherever the output of the pipeline is redirected to.

Answer (score 3):

> `{...}` forces to run the commands inside the curly brackets in the main shell

This is not a good description of what braces do in general. Braces group commands in a way that doesn't create a subshell. In other words, braces do not, in themselves create a subshell: code in braces is executed in the same shell as if there were no braces, as opposed to code in parentheses which is always executed in a subshell (so its redirections, variables, and so on do not affect the parent shell or any other shell).

The point of braces is to allow writing complex commands where the syntax expects a single command. For example, in `command1 | { command2; command3; command4; }` (note that the spaces and the final semicolon are necessary), the right-hand side of the pipe is `{ command2; command3; command4; }`. The command `{ command2; command3; command4; }` executes `command2`, then `command3`, then `command4`. All of these commands take input from the pipe. (Since the commands run successively, `command3` gets whatever input is left after `command2` runs, and so on.)

Answer (score 3):

think of the braces as an unnamed function.   e.g.

```
command234 () { command2; command3; command4; }

command1 | command234
```

gives the same result.  when things get too complicated, i prefer to name the  grouping.  if only for testing.

Answer (score 2):

The standard output of `command1` will be used for the first command in the command block which starts reading from standard input.  In most cases, this will be `command2`.

Comment: this clarifies it, thought of something different, thank you

Comment: so command1 is sending from a subshell into {command2...} which is in the main shell,right?

Comment: @sharkant It depends on the shell implementation. Some shells run all commands in a pipeline in separate subshells, some optimize them.